# Is there isspace in c#?

Tags: c#, whitespace

i was thinking that is there any way to check if argument contains characters like space, horizontal, vertical tab, formfeed, carriage return or a newline. Kinda like isspace but in c#. Is that possible?

Comment: try writing your own? The logic is simple

Comment: You probably shouldn't ask yes/no questions unless you actually want a yes/no answer.  As it is, the correct answer to your question is simply, "Yes".  If you want to know *how* to determine if a string/char contains whitespace, then ask that.

Comment: You say `contains`... I don't think that word means what you think it does.

Comment: @SLaks Why not.  If he has a string and wants to know if it contains whitespace, that seems reasonable.

Comment: @Servy: That's not what `isspace` means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Char.IsWhiteSpace` is designed for this purpose.  For example, I have used this before when parsing a string, example:

```
public int EatWhitespace(string input, int pos)
{
    while(Char.IsWhiteSpace(input[pos])
        ++pos;
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

just look under `Char` and you will find your answer.

[image]

Comment: @jp2code, meet back later and discuss `Char.IsLowSurrogate`? :)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static bool ContainsWhiteSpace(this string text)
{
    return text.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works with the Regex namespace:

```
public bool HasSpace( string input )
{
   return( Regex.Match( input, "\s" ) );
}
```

`Regex.Match` will compare the string to the regular expression pattern; `"\s"` matches all whitespace characters.

Comment: Ah.  Three minutes ago I had never heard of `isspace()`.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer, its an extension method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx